# Error C2678: бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "std::istream"

Tags: c++

Алгоритм идентификации.

Задание: при разработке механизма идентификации и аутентификации проверить пароль(в пароле должны чередоваться русские и  латинские буквы и его длина не должна превышать 15 символов).

Решение мое:

```
#include "LAB4.h"
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice != 2) {
        choice = menu();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            if (check_pass())
                cout << "Пароль удовлетворяет условиям.\n";
            else
                cout << "Пароль не удовлетворяет условиям!\n";
            break;
        case 2:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int menu()
{
    cout << "Выберите нужный пункт меню.\n";
    cout << "1.Проверить пароль\n";
    cout << "2. Выход\n";
    cout << "Ваш выбор: ";
    int ch = 0;
    cin >> ch;
    return ch;
}

bool check_pass()
{
    string passEN = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
    string passRU /*char *passEN */  = /*new char */ "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz";
    int ctr = 0;
    cout << "Требования к паролю:\n1.Пароль должен содержать 12 символов.\n2.В пароле чередуются буквы и цифры.\n";
    cout << "Введите пароль: ";
    string pass;
    cin >> pass;
    cout << "Длина пароля -> " << pass.length() << endl;
    int len = pass.length();        //длина пароля
    int lenEN = passEN.length();        //длина англ алфавита
    int lenRU = passRU.length();        //длина рус алфавита
    if (len <= 15)
        for (int i = 0; i < lenRU; i++) {
            if ((isalpha(passRU[i]) && isalpha(passEN[i + 1])) || (isalpha(passEN[i]) && isalpha(passRU[i + 1]))) {
                ctr = ctr + 1;
            }
            if (ctr == len)
                return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> `1>error C2678: бинарный ">>": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "std::istream" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)`

Код h файла:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int menu();
bool check_pass();
```

Почему ошибка вылезает и как от нее избавиться, чтобы все заработало.

Comment: `<string.h>`?

Comment: Укажите компилятор, в gcc 4.7 такой проблемы не возникает

Answer (score 1):

operator>> не перегружен для istream и string, только для C-строк (char*). Используйте лучше getline и, если нужно, проверяйте в полученной строке наличие пробелов.

А Вы уверены, что isalpha работает для кириллицы? На самом деле, нет. Нужно использовать wstring, wchar_t и функции для работы с ними (см. заголовок cwchar). К тому же, придется получать строку wstring из wcin и уже с нею работать. Совет: для начала отработайте программу только на латинице и уже потом переходите к кириллице.

Comment: @mikillskegg isalpha использует текущую локаль http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha
так что с ней все впорядке